# What is the fault of my "proof" that every operator have a closed extension?

Tags: functional-analysis

I know from textbook that not every linear operator on an Banach space can be extended to a closed operator, but I do not find any such example. However, I write a "proof" below that every operator have a closed extension. Would anyone give me an counterexample and point out where is the fault in my proof?

Proof: Suppose $X$ is a Banach space, and $T:D(T)\subset X\to X$ is a linear operator. $T$ is closed iff the graph norm $$||x||_G = ||x||+||Tx||$$ is complete. Now if it is not complete, we can extend $D(T)$ into a Banach space $\widetilde{D(T)}$ under norm $||\cdot||_G$. If $\{x_n\}\subset D(T)$ and $||x_n - x||_G \to 0$, then $||x_n - x||\to 0$, thus $x\in X$, i.e. $\widetilde{D(T)}\subset X$. Now we can define
$$\widetilde{T}(x) := \lim_{n\to\infty}T(x_n)$$
and $\widetilde{T}:\widetilde{D(T)}\to X$ is a closed operator, since $||\cdot||_G = ||\cdot||+||\widetilde{T}(\cdot)||$ is a complete norm.

Comment: I am not an expert on these things. Imho the proof does not show the claim at all. You prove: an operator can be extended to be closed. You do not show that the extension is well-defined, i.e., independent of the sequence. The claim $\tilde D(T) \subset X$ has no proof, it is most likely wrong.

Comment: $\widetilde{D(T)}\subset X$ is certainly wrong.

Comment: What completion process are you using? Are you taking the $X$-closure of $D(T)$ or are you using any of the standard metric space completion processes. If the latter, you are introducing elements in $\tilde D$ which are not themselves elements of $X$, which faults your conclusions $\|x_n-x\|_G\to0\implies\|x_n-x\|\to0$ since the latter statement has no meaning if $x\notin X$. I’m also not convinced you want to be taking the completion of $D(T)$. Don’t you want to be taking the completion of the graph?

Comment: Thank you all. I am now aware of that $\widetilde{D(T)}\subset X$ is wrong. I have a further question: is there a simple example that a linear operator cannot be extended to a closed operator?

Comment: For an example, take an unbounded operator with $D(T)=X$.  This isn't closed by the Closed Graph Theorem and it obviously can't be extended to anything but itself.